# Classes have not been declared but they were included?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, scope

I have these two classes that need each other and inherited from the same class. Wehn I compile Seller.h, it compiles fine but when I compile Buyer.h I get errors from Seller.h.

So when i compile Buyer.h I get errors such as :

```
Seller.h:14:16: error: âBuyerâ has not been declared

  void addBuyer(Buyer*);

                ^
Seller.h:15:14: error: âBuyerâ was not declared in this scope
  std::vector<Buyer*>  getBuyers() const;

Seller.h:20:17: error: âOrderâ has not been declared
  void fillOrder(Order*);
             ^
```

They are #included but it still says out of scope.

```
#ifndef SELLER_H
#define SELLER_H
#include "Entity.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Inventory.h"
#include "Buyer.h"
#include "Order.h"
class Seller : public virtual Entity
{
public:
        Seller(const std::string &, const std::string &, double=0.0);
        virtual~Seller(){}
        void addBuyer(Buyer*);
        std::vector<Buyer*>  getBuyers() const;
        void setInventory(Inventory*);
        Inventory* getInventory() const;
        virtual void list() const override;
        virtual void step() override;
        void fillOrder(Order*);
private:
        Inventory* inv;
        std::vector <Buyer*> buyers;
};
#endif
```

Buyer.h

```
#ifndef BUYER_H
#define BUYER_H
#include <string>
#include "Entity.h"
#include <queue>
#include "Order.h"
#include "Seller.h"
class Buyer : public virtual Entity
{
public:
        Buyer(const std::string &, const std::string &, double =0.0 );
        virtual ~Buyer(){}
        void addSeller(Seller *);
        std::queue <Seller *> getSellers() const;
        void addOrder(Order *);
        std::queue <Order*>  getOrders() const;
        virtual void list() const override;
        virtual void step() override;

private:
        std::queue <Order*>  orders;
        std::queue <Seller*> sellers;
};
#endif
```

Comment: You have a cyclic include dependency. That can't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c

Comment: I see it now. But how about the Order class? It's not really cyclic and I get an error for it as well

Answer (score 2):

You have a cyclic dependency between `Seller` and `Buyer`.  This will never work because the compiler requires the declaration of `Seller` in order to compile `Buyer`... yet it also requires the declaration of `Buyer` to compile `Seller`.

You can instead forward declare your classes because all you actually use are pointers to these types. For example:

```
#ifndef SELLER_H
#define SELLER_H
#include "Entity.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Inventory.h"
#include "Order.h"

// forward declaration of Buyer
class Buyer;

class Seller : public virtual Entity
{
public:
        Seller(const std::string &, const std::string &, double=0.0);
        virtual ~Seller(){}
        void addBuyer(Buyer*);
        std::vector<Buyer*>  getBuyers() const;
        void setInventory(Inventory*);
        Inventory* getInventory() const;
        virtual void list() const override;
        virtual void step() override;
        void fillOrder(Order*);
private:
        Inventory* inv;
        std::vector <Buyer*> buyers;
};
#endif
```

If you had an instance of `Buyer` as a member of `Seller` (i.e., `Buyer _buyer;`), or if any method took/returned an instance of `Buyer`, you would be forced to change your structure.  Since you don't have that problem, a forward declaration will suffice.

---

As an aside, and admitting that I am not privy to the structure of your program, it is usually a bad sign when one sees so many naked pointers being used in a C++ program. You can store instances. You can use safe pointers (`shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`) depending on your ownership semantics.

For example, `addBuyer` can easily take a `Buyer&` instead of a pointer. Now you don't have to worry about invalid pointers.  I'm assuming that you add these to your `buyers` vector... but how are you guaranteeing that these pointers remain valid for the lifetime of a `Seller` instance?  You can't; you're at the mercy of whomever called `addBuyer`.

Why not just store a `std::vector<Buyer>` and take a reference in your add method?  Is the cost of a copy so prohibitive as to warrant this design?  If so, could you not use `shared_ptr`?

Comment: This is for a project and I was given some instructions, like using pointers and such.

Comment: I have a question about the Order class. Since my seller class also gives me an error for it. Why is it out of scope? I included it

Comment: @user3582405: Well, you'd have to post your `Order` declaration, but could it be the same problem?  Does `Order` use `Seller`?

Comment: No, it's just a helping class to make objects from. But both seller and buyer use order. Is it that any class that they both share produce that error?

Comment: Are you certain that error persists after fixing the problem I described?  If it does you'll need to show us that header file.